# Find and replace after a string after a specific character

Tags: text-processing, string, replace

I have the following lines in my input file and I would like to replace all the text after "=" sign with a new string, say "good".

Again, I would like to do this only for certain strings in the line.

Input file:

```
$myvar1=var1
$myvar2=var2
$myname=name
$myage=age
$mycity=city
```

Output file:

```
$myvar1=var1
$myvar2=var2
$myname=good
$myage=good
$mycity=good
```

Comment: What "certain strings" are these?

Comment: In the above Input File, I would like to keep the 1st 2 lines [$myvar1 and $myvar2..] as-is.. That is what i call "certain string' as i dont want to touch those lines

Comment: Why? Because they're the first two lines or because they contain the string "myvar", or what?

Comment: B'Cos they contain strings $myvar1 and $myvar2

Answer (score 2):

I think sed is the proper tool for what you want to do, here is my implementation - instead of looking for something, I negate what you are protecting:

`sed -r '/^((\$myvar1)|(\$myvar2))/!s/=.*$/="good"/g'`

Comment: I get an error message : not a recognized flag r

Comment: @veekay - That's probably because you don't have that option. Try it with -E.

Comment: that does not work either..

Comment: What does it say? What system and sed version are you using?

Comment: am a novice here. how to find it..

Comment: Run this: lsb_release -a;sed --version|head -1

Comment: lsb_release not found

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? With GNU sed.

```
sed -E '/var[0-9]/!s/(=).*/\1good/' file
```

Comment: I get an error message : not a recognized flag E

Comment: Could it be that you the dash `-` is missing?

Answer (score 1):

To skip the first two lines, you could use:

```
sed '3,$s/=.*/=good/' file
```

This does the substitution from line 3 to the last line (`$`).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you know ahead of time the variable names (e.g. `$myname`, `$myage`, and `$mycity`) that you would like to change, you can use `sed`:

```
sed -i '/^\$myname=/s/=.*$/=good/g' input_file_name
sed -i '/^\$myage=/s/=.*$/=good/g' input_file_name
sed -i '/^\$mycity/s/=.*$/=good/g' input_file_name
```

Basically, this just says to only run a regular expression on lines that start with a certain match (lines with `^\$myname=`, `^\$myage=`, or `^\$mycity=`), and replace the equal sign plus everything following (`=.*$`) with an equal sign and the appropriate string (`=good`).

NOTE: If the `-i` option is not available with your version of `sed`, consider the following instead for the same effect:

```
sed '/^\$myname=/s/=.*$/=good/g' input_file_name > output_file_name
sed '/^\$myage=/s/=.*$/=good/g' input_file_name > output_file_name
sed '/^\$mycity/s/=.*$/=good/g' input_file_name > output_file_name
```

Comment: sed -i does not seem to be working for me

Comment: Are you using BSD/macOS? Does `sed -i '' …` work?

Comment: Why `-i` at all? OP writes about input file and output file, not modifying the input file. And there is no reason for calling `sed` three times. Finally, your second line contains an error.

Comment: Thanks for catching the mistake on the second line. I also understand your points, but because OP was being so vague, I do not planning on deleting this answer. The other answers assumed that OP always wanted to substitute `good` into the lines. I separated it into three separate calls so that it's easier if OP actually wanted to change each specific line to something different. Also, based on the content being substituted, I interpreted OP's intentions to be bulk modifying BASH/perl/etc. code, which would make the `-i` option potentially useful under certain circumstances.

Comment: I get an error message : not a recognized flag -i

Comment: What system are you using? I edited my answer for a version with the same effect without using the `-i` option. Good luck figuring out your problem.